# FlutterでAutoSizeTextを使用する時に文字を選択可能にしたい

Tags: flutter, dart

今文章の羅列の解決案を探しています、
dartのプラグインの中にAutoSizeTextを見つけました。
ですが、使ってみると欲しい機能がありませんでした、
それは文字選択機能です。
もちろんSelectableTextを使ってもいいですが、それだと自動サイズもrich文字の機能も利用できなくなります、
どうしたらいいですか。